# Change the text of the inner tag using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to change the `inner text` of a tag in HTML obtained using `Beautifulsoup`.

Example:

```
<a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Foo</a>
```

turns into:

```
<a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Bar</a>
```

I have managed to get the tag by it's id by:

```
HTMLDocument.find(id='websiteName')
```

But I'm not beeing able to change the `inner text`of the tag:

```
print HTMLDocument.find(id='websiteName')

a = HTMLDocument.find(id='websiteName')
a = a.replaceWith('<a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Bar</a>')

// I have tried using this as well
a = a.replaceWith('Bar')

print a
```

Output:

```
<a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Foo</a>
<a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Foo</a>
```

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect this. Now I'm doing `a = a.replace('Bar')` and then printing the `a` variable directly

Comment: what version of Beautifulsoup are you using ?

Comment: Does the method `.replaceWith()` return anything?

Comment: @PRMoureu Version 3.2.1

Comment: @AK47 I'm not sure. I have seen some examples like this on SO. I have tried using `print a.replaceWith('Test')` but without any luck

Comment: you should update it to version 4 (btw, method name changed to [`replace_with`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with))

Comment: @PRMoureu I have tried `print HTMLDocument.find(id='websiteName').replace_with("Foo")` but it's just returning the original string

Comment: `replace_with` returns the stuff that was replaced. You should not reassign it to original variable. Change `a = a.replaceWith(...` with just `a.replaceWith(...` Ref: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with

Comment: Note that `BeautifulSoup` is the obsolete library - you want `bs4` aka `BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try by changing the string element :

```
HTMLDocument.find(id='websiteName').string.replace_with('Bar')
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """
<a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Foo</a>
"""
soup = soup(html, 'lxml')
result = soup.find(id='websiteName')

print(result)
# >>> <a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Foo</a>

result.string.replace_with('Bar')
print(result)
# >>> <a href="index.html" id="websiteName">Bar</a>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: It's worth nothing that the method `replace_with()` worked on my version which is `3.2.1`

Comment: Thanks for noting that, i could not test this version