# Get the full text of content intersected by a tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Say I have some HTML like the following.

```
<p>This is the beginning of the text. <em>Italicized middle</em> This is the end of the text.</p>
```

It's a tag with another tag inside. I can use Beautiful Soup to get the contents of it:

```
list_of_tags = full_html.findAll()

for tag in list_of_tags:
    print(tag.find(text = True))
```

That prints:

```
This is the beginning of the text. 
Italicized middle
```

It cuts off the end part—everything after the contained tag. How can find that part?

Comment: how about just using a simple algo instead of using beautiful soup to achieve what you want?

Comment: @Mox What do you mean by that? Do you mean parsing it and stripping the tags in a different way?

Comment: BS is appropriate for parsing HTML--that's not the problem. Why not just use `elem.text`? This gives the entire text content, for example: `print(BeautifulSoup('<div>a<div>b</div>c</div>', 'lxml').find('div').text)` prints `abc`. Otherwise, I'm a bit uncertain what you're actually trying to locate/produce here. Do you need the before and after and child elements as distinct entities? I think NavigableString is your friend for that, potentially.

Comment: @ggorlen Good idea—I had forgotten about that. That works great for extracting the text, but I'm trying to preserve the italicization in my output file. The .text method doesn't allow me to tell that text was originally in an <em> tag. Do you know if this is possible somehow?

Comment: Sure. What exactly are you trying to accomplish though? Just get each child in a `p` and differentiate `<em>`s from plain text nodes or something more?

Comment: @ggorlen I actually just figured it out. If you're curious I posted an answer. Thanks for your help! I just go through beforehand in a separate loop to add markdown tags to the italicized tags.

Comment: Sure, happy to help although I still have no idea what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ggorlen's help, I modified my program to work a little differently. It first modifies the contents of an  tag so they are italicized in markup (I decided this was a good way to distinguish it for my purposes.

```
for tag in tag_list:
    if tag.name == "em":
        tag.string.replace_with("*" + tag.string + "*")
    if tag.name == "strong":
        tag.string.replace_with("**" + tag.string + "**")
```

Then, in a separate loop, I got the text of everything that wasn't a tag I had modified above (otherwise it would be recursive), then added its .text to a list.

```
for tag in tag_list:
    if tag.name == "strong" || tag.name == "em":
        continue

    else:
        my_list.append(tag.text)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to do what you're trying to do. If you'd provide more details about how the replacements work, I can offer an answer. Looks like you're trying to convert to markdown?

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah, I want to convert it to markdown. I used a method from the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024877/change-the-text-of-the-inner-tag-using-beautifulsoup-python) to modify the text in the <em> tags. My goal here is to get all the text from the tags but still have a way of knowing what was in a child tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the data without separation, you can use the following methods.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<p>This is the beginning of the text. <em>Italicized middle</em> This is the end of the text.</p>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.p.text)
```

Result:

```
This is the beginning of the text. Italicized middle This is the end of the text.
```